# Spring Boot Thymeleaf ViewResolver on Rest controllers

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

Greeting.

I have a Spring Boot app (v. 1.4.1).
Previously set up the `Thymeleaf` from

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.nekohtml</groupId>
    <artifactId>nekohtml</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.22</version>
</dependency>
```

`nekohtml` - to support the not strict html in thymeleaf templates.
I use Thymeleaf templates only for the email templating. The app is representing tho REST API, all controllers returning `json` data.

However after i set the Thymeleaf for emails, some requests are looking for Thymeleaf templates for them and returning `code 500`.

Thymeleaf config (yml, this is all config for thymeleaf, no other JAVA configs, Spring Boot Handling everything):

```
  thymeleaf:
    check-template-location: true
    prefix: classpath:/templates/
    suffix: .html
    mode: LEGACYHTML5
    encoding: UTF-8
    content-type: text/html 
    cache: true
```

example controller and error:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public JsonResponse AddUser(@RequestBody @Valid User user, WebRequest request) throws SQLException {
    String result = userService.RegisterUser(user);
    if(result.equals("done")) {
        try {
            eventPublisher.publishEvent(new OnRegistrationCompleteEvent(user, request.getLocale()));
        } catch (Exception me) {
            return new JsonResponse("FAIL", "Unknown on event publishing: "+ me.getMessage());
        }
        return new JsonResponse("OK", "");

    } else if(result.equals("duplicate")) {
        return new JsonResponse("FAIL", "duplicate");
    }
    return new JsonResponse("FAIL", "Unknown");
}
```

Error:

```
2016-11-25 11:02:04.285 DEBUG 15552 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : Authorization successful
2016-11-25 11:02:04.285 DEBUG 15552 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    : RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
2016-11-25 11:02:04.285 DEBUG 15552 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : /register reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding with original chain
2016-11-25 11:02:04.289 DEBUG 15552 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing POST request for [/api/register]
2016-11-25 11:02:04.291 DEBUG 15552 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /register
2016-11-25 11:02:04.294 DEBUG 15552 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public com.springapp.models.common.JsonResponse com.springapp.controllers.api.IndexController.AddUser(com.springapp.models.common.User,org.springframework.web.context.request.WebRequest) throws java.sql.SQLException]
2016-11-25 11:02:04.329 DEBUG 15552 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor : Read [class com.springapp.models.common.User] as "application/json;charset=UTF-8" with [org.springframework.http.converter.json.MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter@682ef707]
2016-11-25 11:02:15.620 DEBUG 15552 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.w.servlet.view.BeanNameViewResolver  : No matching bean found for view name 'register'
2016-11-25 11:02:15.635 DEBUG 15552 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView@1a462947] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
2016-11-25 11:02:15.647 ERROR 15552 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.thymeleaf.TemplateEngine             : [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-1] Exception processing template "register": Error resolving template "register", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
2016-11-25 11:02:15.651 DEBUG 15552 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Error rendering view [org.thymeleaf.spring4.view.ThymeleafView@1a462947] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'

org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "register", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

Comment: Be carefull about - prefix: classpath:/templates/ - set your prefix and put your templates in /WEB-INF/templates because if thymeleaf is configured to use ClassLoaderTemplateResolver then it will search for templates inside jars.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sorry everyone, that was my mistake. Previously i migrated the app from Spring MVC to Spring Boot with splitting it to REST API and front-end.
Particularly that controller wasn't annotated as `@RestController`. Fixed.

Comment: And I did exactly the same thing and fixed it in the same way.